# How to create a list of products with a menu that has sort function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to create a list of products and sort them by selecting different filter options on the menu like the one here: http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=124&IsSingle=1&Category=24&name=Network-Storage-NAS

How hard would it be to program this using php and javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "how hard"? It seems a rather simple task, what you need is: MYSQL: a database to store your product db;PHP: some backend to manage your product db;  when a user changes the select value, you make the page reload. I think the hardest part is the db management, and the longest one data entry.

Comment: I should say this is nearly a vague question. Is it one in the left hand filter menu? To create something like one in that website it would take me 4 to 8 hrs. Again it depends on the framework that you use. But logically it is fairly simple. you send the selection to the URL and in your query add those conditions in where clause..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit complex to discuss how to design a system like that but this is easily accomplished with `ORDER BY` in PHP and MySQL:

```
$order = $_GET['order'];
if ($order)
{
    switch ($order)
    {
        case 'p':
            $order = 'price';
            break;

        case 'n':
            $order = 'name';
            break;

        case 'r':
            $order = 'rating';
            break;

        default:
            $order = 'price';
            break;
    }
}

$Sql = "SELECT product_name, price, rating FROM products ORDER BY $order ASC";
// do your SQL stuff here
```

On HTML and Javascript you can do something like:

```
<select name="filter" onchange="window.location.href='filter.php?order='+this.value">
    <option value="p">Price</option>
    <option value="n">Name</option>
    <option value="r">Rating</option>
</select>
```

Just an idea but this can be improved to much much better approach.

Comment: what about excluding certain results after retrieving from mysql?

Comment: you may need to write a code to iterate through the results from MySQL and filter out certain records that you don't want to be displayed but it'd be best to filter them out using the query too so you save some processing and coding time.

Comment: Could you explain this line of code in detail please? onchange="window.location.href='filter.php?order='+this.value"

Comment: it means when the drop-down changed value (onchange), set the window's location to `filter.php?order=` getting the drop-down's selected value `this.value`. `this` refers to the drop-down itself, `value` is the current value

Comment: What about "order" after "filter.php?". What happens if I remove "this." before "value"?

Comment: `order` is the GET variable that you'll use for getting the field value to your PHP e.g. `$_GET['order']`. as for `this` it won't work if you remove it, it's a reference to the drop-down object.

Comment: is the plus sign before "this.value" necessary?

Comment: yes, it's for concatenating `filter.php?order=` with `this.value` otherwise you will be sending the literal string `filter.php?order=this.value`

Comment: What if I want the user to be able to select multiple categories at once? For example, I have the word "price" with 3 radio buttons below: "1 dollar", "2 dollar", or "3 dollar" and another word "size" with 3 radio buttons below: "small","medium", "large". I select the radio button "1 button" and the radio button "small". In the PHP tags, I would be able to use $price = $_POST['price']; and $size=$_POST['size']; to retrieve the "1 dollar" value AND "small" value.

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about the sort feature on new egg and most other sites it is very easy if you know SQL and PHP. The product data is stored in a database and a form submission or ajax call is made when the sort menu is changed. The value is typically also stored on a session for use on later pages as the customer pages through the results. The sort order is used to set the ORDER BY clause in the SQL query that retrieves the data from the database. That's all you need to accomplish this.